# How to get value from then and assign it to variable

Tags: javascript

How to get value from then and assign it to variables?

```
const country = new Country();

country
    .getCountry()
    .then((results) => {
        ui.paint(results);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

const variable = country.name;
```

Comment: `.then` only works with promises. What does `Country.getCountry()` look like?

Comment: @cSharp 
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object